# Image upload code isnt working

Tags: php, mysql, html

I am trying to simply place an image in the folder using image upload in php but it is not working, please help me what is the problem with it.. thanx :)

this is my code for `setup.php`

```
<?php include("../includes/config.php"); ?>
<?php
    if ($_SESSION["isadmin"])
    {

        $con=mysql_connect($dbserver,$dbusername,$dbpassword);
        if (!$con) { die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error()); }

        mysql_select_db($dbname, $con);

        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM setup WHERE (id=".$_SESSION["id"].")");
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
        {
            $title = $row['title'];
            $theme = $row['theme'];
        }
        mysql_close($con);
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Admdin Home</title>
    <link rel="StyleSheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
</head>
<body>
    <?php include("includes/header.php"); ?>
    <?php include("includes/nav.php"); ?>
    <?php include("includes/aside.php"); ?>
    <div id="maincontent">

        <div id="breadcrumbs">
            <a href="">Home</a> >
            <a href="">Setup</a> >
            Customization
        </div>
        <h2>Customize</h2>
        <?php
            if (isset($_GET["status"]))
            {
                if($_GET["status"]==1)
                {
                    echo("<strong>Customization Done!</strong>");
                }
                if($_GET["status"]==2)
                {
                    echo("<strong>Customization Error!!</strong>");
                }
            }
        ?>
        <form method="post"  action="setup-action.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
            <label>Title Of Your Organization:</label>  <input type="text" name="title" value="<?       php echo $title; ?>" /> <br /> <br />
            <label>Select Theme</label>
            <select name="theme" value="<?php echo $theme; ?>">
                <option value="Default">Default</option>
                <option value="Dark">Dark</option>
                <option value="White">White</option>
            </select>
            <br /> <br />
            <label>Choose Your Logo Here</label><input type="file" name="file"/><br /> <br />      
            <input type="submit" name="Upload" value="Upload" />
        </form>
    </div>

</body>
<?php include("includes/footer.php"); ?>
</html>
<?php
    }
    else
    {
        header("Location: ".$fullpath."login/unauthorized.php");
    }
?>
```

this is `setup-action.php`

```
<?php include("../includes/config.php");?>
<?php
if(isset($_FILES["file"]))
{
    if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif") || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] ==     "image/jpeg") || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg"))
   && ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 1000000))
    {
        if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
        {
            echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br />";
        }

        if (file_exists("../graphics/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
        {
            echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
        }
        else
        {
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["name"], "../graphics/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
            echo "Stored in: " . "../graphics/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
        }
     }
}
else
{
    echo "Invalid file";
}
?>
<?php
    $title=$_POST["title"];
    $theme=$_POST["theme"];
    $con=mysql_connect($dbserver,$dbusername,$dbpassword);
    if (!$con) { die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error()); }

    mysql_select_db($dbname, $con);
    $result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM setup WHERE id=".$_SESSION['id']);
    $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
    if ($num_rows > 0)
    {
        {
            mysql_query("UPDATE setup  SET title='".$title."' , theme='".$theme."'WHERE     id=".$_SESSION['id']);
            header("Location:setup.php?status=1");
        }
    }
    else {
        header("Location:setup.php?status=2");
    }
    mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: its not giving any errors, the other code is working as im customizing my webpage thrugh this code, evrything is working perfectly except image upload, please tell me whether my code is wrong or whats the problem... i think i have used the code incorrectly

Comment: What output do you get from your PHP? There are a lot of echo statements in there.... Do you get no output at all?

Comment: iam getting all the edited data like i can change the theme n its updating theme successfully, iam changing the name of the company, its updating successfully, but for image upload code its giving no response...

Answer (score 3):

I am not completely certain about this, but I think you need to use tmp_name in the move_uploaded_file, as the file receives a temporary name and location untill moved.

Like so:

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],"your/path/".$_FILES["file"]["name"]);
```

Hope it works... Everything else did seem perfectly ok to me.

Answer (score 0):

Need to use the uploaded file's temp name in the move_uploaded_file() function. The temp name contains the path to the file saved in temporary storage